# How to expand/collapse multiple separate jquery accordions on one page

Tags: jquery

I have a razor page where I want a single separate collapsible header for each line item in a model. I want to create a button on the page where it finds every accordion on the page with a certain class and expands them.

I have it very close to working but after expanding something that was closed at page load you have to click the header of that accordion twice to get it to collapse again

This is roughly the razor code I have

```
<button id="expand-button" class="ExpandButton">Expand/Collapse All</button>
foreach (ViewDetailViewModel di in Model.Details)
{
    string accordionClass, headerClass;
    if (di.RelevantForUser)
    {
        accordionClass = "expandedAccordion";
        headerClass = "relevantHeader";
    }
    else
    {
        accordionClass = "collapsedAccordion";
        if (di.Type == LineType.Cancelled)
        {
            headerClass = "cancelledHeader";
        }
        else
        {
            headerClass = "irrelevantHeader";
        }
    }

    <div id="accordion-lineitem-@(di.LineNum)" class="@(accordionClass) lineItemAccordion">
        <h3 class="@(headerClass) lineItemHeader">Line Item @di.LineNum</h3>
        <div id="lineitem-@(di.LineNum)-panel" class="lineitem-panel">
          <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

And this is the jquery to create the accordions

```
$(function() {
  $(".expandedAccordion").accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      icons : { header : 'ui-icon-circle-plus', activeHeader :'ui-icon-circle-minus'}

  });
  $(".collapsedAccordion").accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
      icons: { header: 'ui-icon-circle-plus', activeHeader: 'ui-icon-circle-minus' }
  });
});
```

With all of that code the accordions work perfectly before I add in the Expand/Collapse button code

```
$('#expand-button')
    .click(function (event) {
         var panels = $('.lineitem-panel');
         var icons = $('#details .ui-accordion-header-icon');
         if (panels.data('slided') === true) {
             panels.data('slided', false);
             panels.slideUp();
         }
         else {
             panels.data('slided', true);
             panels.slideDown();
         }
});
```

The Expand/Collapse all button actually works for visually collapsing/expanding the accordions, but it does not update the "state" in jquery of each accordion.

For example, if lineitem-3 was loaded as a collapsed accordion and then the Expand/Collapse all button is clicked, the collapsed accordion will visually expand.  However jquery doesn't recognize the accordion as being now expanded: the icon doesn't change and jquery doesn't understand that the panel is expanded. 
Because of this, to re-collapse line-item3 using the icon I have to click it twice: once to put it in the "expanded" state to jquery (even though it's already visually expanded) and the second one to put it in the "collapsed" state which collapses it (both visually and in jquery state).

So my specific question is: is there an alternative way to collapse/expand all accordions where jquery will recognize the "state" switch

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer myself and wanted to post it here if anyone ever stumbled upon this.  It was actually really straight forward, just use the accordion divs instead of the panel divs and leverage the active attribute of the accordion

```
       $('#expand-button')
        .click(function (event) {
            var accordiondivs = $('.lineItemAccordion')
            if (accordiondivs.data('slided') === true) {
                accordiondivs.data('slided', false);
                accordiondivs.accordion('option', { active: false })
            }
            else if (accordiondivs.data('slided') === false) {
                accordiondivs.data('slided', true);
                accordiondivs.accordion('option', "active", 0)
            }
            else {
                accordiondivs.data('slided', true);
                $('.collapsedAccordion').accordion('option', 'active', 0 );
            }
    });
```